# Should I add a reverse reference from my ScheduledTaskAgent, or copy code from the foreground project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

I've added a `ScheduledTaskAgent` project affiliated with my WP8 project - I added a reference in the WP8 project to the `ScheduledTaskAgent` project. In the `ScheduledTaskAgent` project's `OnInvoke()` code, I want to query a WAMS table that is already defined in the WP8 project. The WAMS code is "greek" to the `ScheduledTaskAgent` project. IOW, this is not recognized by it:

```
   protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
   {
                IMobileServiceTable<WAMS_INVITATIONS> table =     
    app.MobileService.GetTable<WAMS_INVITATIONS>();    
                MobileServiceTableQuery<String> query = <bla>;
                return await query.ToListAsync();
                . . .
    }
```

...which is not at all surprising, because "app" is the other project's `App.xaml.cs` class, and `WAMS_INVITATIONS` is the class in the other project that defines the table to be queried. So...is it okay for a `ScheduledTaskAgent` project to add a reference back to the foreground project that references it, or will this circular reference cause problems? Otherwise, I need to copy over the `MobileService` declaration from App.xaml.cs and the table definition class from the foreground project?

I made IMobileServiceTable understandable to the compiler by adding a reference to "Windows Azure Mobile Services Managed Client" to the ScheduledTaskAgent project.

Comment: No, you won't be able to reference your UI Project.  It has dependencies that are not allowed in background tasks.  Move the MobileService code to a class library and reference it in your application and your background task projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

kindasimple's answer is correct, however once you successfully get your agent building, it's likely you will hit a known issue: the current Mobile Services SDK cannot be used in background tasks on Windows Phone. The SDK makes references to UI components and your app may not pass certification due to that. We are aware of the problem and working on a fix, just wanted to give you a heads up.